# How can I delete all rows of a DataFrame that have an NA in a specific column?

Tags: dataframe, julia

What is the most elegant way to delete all rows in a DataFrame having an `NA` value in a specific column?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642257/how-to-mutate-a-dataframe You should add some code to your question to get people willing to help started.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know whether what follows is the most elegant way of deleting all rows having an `NA` in a specific column, but that is *one* way.

#### Generating a toy DataFrame

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = 2:2:20)
10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | 2  |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | 8  |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
| 6   | 6  | 12 |
| 7   | 7  | 14 |
| 8   | 8  | 16 |
| 9   | 9  | 18 |
| 10  | 10 | 20 |

julia> df[[1,4,8],symbol("B")] = NA
NA

julia> df
10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | NA |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | NA |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
| 6   | 6  | 12 |
| 7   | 7  | 14 |
| 8   | 8  | NA |
| 9   | 9  | 18 |
| 10  | 10 | 20 |
```

#### Filtering out rows whose `"B"`-column element is `NA`

```
julia> df[~isna(df[:,symbol("B")]),:]
7x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 2  | 4  |
| 2   | 3  | 6  |
| 3   | 5  | 10 |
| 4   | 6  | 12 |
| 5   | 7  | 14 |
| 6   | 9  | 18 |
| 7   | 10 | 20 |

julia> df
10x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | NA |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 3  | 6  |
| 4   | 4  | NA |
| 5   | 5  | 10 |
| 6   | 6  | 12 |
| 7   | 7  | 14 |
| 8   | 8  | NA |
| 9   | 9  | 18 |
| 10  | 10 | 20 |
```

#### Deleting rows whose `"B"`-column element is `NA`

```
julia> deleterows!(df,find(isna(df[:,symbol("B")])))
7x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 2  | 4  |
| 2   | 3  | 6  |
| 3   | 5  | 10 |
| 4   | 6  | 12 |
| 5   | 7  | 14 |
| 6   | 9  | 18 |
| 7   | 10 | 20 |

julia> df
7x2 DataFrame
| Row | A  | B  |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 2  | 4  |
| 2   | 3  | 6  |
| 3   | 5  | 10 |
| 4   | 6  | 12 |
| 5   | 7  | 14 |
| 6   | 9  | 18 |
| 7   | 10 | 20 |
```

Answer (score 6):

Say `df` is your DataFrame and `A` is the column with missing values. You can do:

```
nonmissingrows = findin(isna(df[:A]), false)
df = df[nonmissingrows, :]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using Lazy
using DataFramesMeta
df2 = @> df @where(!isna(:B))
```

- `@>` is from the [Lazy.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Lazy.jl) package, and it basically rewrites `df` `@where(!isna(:B))` to `@where(df, !isna(:B))`.
- `@where` is provided by the [DataFramesMeta](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFramesMeta.jl) package. The second argument is basically a list of bools of which should rows should be kept and which shouldn't. The special part of these functions is that `:B` can be as short-hand for `df[:B]`

Comment: This tricky bit is the chaining. `@>` is from the lazy.jl package, and it basically  rewrites `df @where(!isna(:B))` to `@where(df, !isna(:B))`. `@where` is provided by the DataFramesMeta package. The second argument is basically a list of bools of which should rows should be kept and which shouldn't. The special part of these functions is that `:B` can be as short-hand for `df[:B]`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all rows contain NA values, simple run this, assuming `df` is a dataframe :

```
completecases!(df)
```

Comment: ```dropmissing!(df)``` is another alternative.